# Pandas - Sum for each unique word

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

> Updated.  Instead of `dict` data, I change for a `dataframe` as input

I'm analyzing a DataFrame with approximately 10,000 rows and 2 columns.

The criteria of my analysis is based on whether certain words appear in a certain cell.

I believe I will be more successful if I know which words are most relevant in terms of values...

###### Foo data to be used as an example:

```py
data = { 'product': ['Dell Notebook I7', 'Dell Notebook I3', 'Logitech mx keys', 'Logitech mx 2'],
         'cost': [1000,1200,300,100]}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | product | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dell Notebook I7 | 1000 |
| 1 | Dell Notebook I3 | 1200 |
| 2 | Logitech mx keys | 300 |
| 3 | Logitech mx 2 | 100 |

Basically, the column `product` shows the product an description.
In the column `cost` shows the product cost.

###### What I want:

I would like to create another dataframe like this:

###### Desired Output:

|  | unique_words | total_cost_for_unique_word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dell | 2200 |
| 4 | Logitech | 2200 |
| 5 | Notebook | 2200 |
| 2 | I3 | 1200 |
| 3 | I7 | 1000 |
| 7 | mx | 400 |
| 6 | keys | 300 |
| 0 | 2 | 100 |

- Column `unique_words` with the list of each word that appears in the column `product`.
- Column `total_cost_for_unique_word` with the sum of the values of products that contain that word.

I've tried searching for posts here from StackOverflow... Also, I've done google research, but I haven't found a solution. Maybe I still don't have the knowledge to find the answer.

If by any chance it has already been answered, please let me know and I will delete the post.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = (df_data
 .assign(unique_words=df['product'].str.split())
 .explode('unique_words')
 .groupby('unique_words', as_index=False)
 .agg(**{'total cost': ('cost' ,'sum')})
 .sort_values('total cost', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
 )
```

Output:

```
  unique_words  total cost
0         Dell        2200
1     Notebook        2200
2           I3        1200
3           I7        1000
4     Logitech         400
5           mx         400
6         keys         300
7            2         100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you first split the product into a list of all words (default is " "):

```
df["product"] = df["product"].str.split()
```

You can then explode this (for each item in the list as a new line), group all these together and sum the costs, then sorting and renaming columns to suit your outcome:

```
df.explode("product").groupby("product",as_index=False).agg("sum").sort_values("cost", ascending=False).rename(columns={"product": "unique_words", "cost", "total_cost_for_unique_word"})
```